# Angular - Dynamically fill a table

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I found it difficult to find a title related to my problem. I am learning angular by doing a project, which consists in preparing forms. Each form can contain various fields stored in a table called Questions(FormId, Name, Message). When the user fills out the form, the data are stored in a table Called Answer(QuestionId, Value). Everything works perfectly so far.

My problem is when I want to display the answer in html table. I tried everything I could with no satisfying result.

Here is my code:

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let item of keyValueRep | keyvalue">{{ item.key }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let k of keyValueReponses">
            <td *ngFor="let i of k | keyvalue">{{ i.value }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

this.idForm = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
if(this.idForm){
        questionService.getQuestionsByForm(this.idForm)
        .subscribe(response => {
          this.questions = response.json();
          let rep: Reponse[] = []

          //*/
          this.questions.forEach(q => {
            this.reponseService.getReponsesByQuestion(q.Id)
            .subscribe(response => {
              rep = response.json();
              console.log(rep)

              this.reponses.push(rep);


              rep.forEach(r => {
                this.reponses.push(r.Valeur);
                this.keyValueRep[r.Question.Name] = r.Valeur;
              });
              console.log(this.keyValueRep);
              this.keyValueReponses.push(this.keyValueRep);
            });
            this.keyValueRep = {};
          });
          console.log(this.keyValueReponses);//*/
        });

      }
```

I wonder if there isn't a simple way doing it. If anyone got an idea, I would be grateful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you are trying to push to responses twice, all at once and other times one by one. `this.keyValueReponses.push(this.keyValueRep);` should be inside the rep.forEach

Comment: Do you have any hooks to play with  `getReponsesByQuestion()` API ?

Comment: Thank you for your Replies. @GopeshSharma I was just trying something with the variable reponses. The only variables that matter are keyValueRep and keyValueReponses. And I tried what you suggested. It doesn't work. getReponsesByQuestion() is an API call (return this.http.get(this.urlQuest + '/' + id);).